# xtext inject or access RootModel into ScopeProvider

Tags: guice, xtext

I am using Xtext 2.3.1

Within my `ScopeProvider` I want to use the currently parsed `rootModel`.
How to do so? Can I inject the RootModel or can I use the context?

```
public class MyLanguageScopeProvider extends AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider {

    public IScope scope_MyLangElement_ref(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        HashMap<QualifiedName, EObject> elements = new HashMap<QualifiedName, EObject>();

        // access model here, sth like:
        RootModel rootModel = // ....

        return new MapBasedScope(elements);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EcoreUtil.getRootContainer(context)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Sebastion.
In my installation it is: `EcoreUtil.getRootContainer(context)`.